# run jetty-runner with jre's java.exe

Tags: jetty

Is there any way that I can run my war file in [jetty-runner](http://webtide.intalio.com/2008/04/jetty-runner/) using jre's java.exe ? If I run it using jdk's java.exe its working fine. But when I run it off using jre's java.exe Spring and Tiles is not working properly. I'm getting the following Exception.

org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/W..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty itself can run fine with the jre like that, but if you're using things like jsp's which require a jdk to compile then you would need a jdk or monkey with the classpath and jsp settings to make sure it uses the ejc dependency we distribute with our jsp jars.  That all assuming that it is spring/tiles there that are using jsps, if they have some other requirement on the jdk I can't say.

Assuming jsps again, alternately look into precompiling those jsps if you absolutely have to run with the jre.  There are a number of approaches for that, we have a maven plugin for it 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-jspc-maven-plugin' and I know there are ant tasks for it as well.

cheers